# how to fiil an array with values from another array in a sub block fashion?

Tags: arrays, r

I have an array given below:

```
d <- array(0, c(750,760))
```

and a data frame "t" given below:

```
str(t)    
'data.frame':   22800 obs. of  2 variables:
     $ Class1: num  6 4 2 1 2 2 2 3 2 2 ...
     $ Class2: num  19 21 23 24 23 23 23 22 23 23 ...
```

since number of observations is 22800 in t dataframe, let i=22800, here

```
sum of Class 1[i] and Class2[i] is always 25
```

now i want to fill the array d such that it only fills a 5 * 5 block of array d every time first with 1 and the times it should fill will be from the value of ith element of Class1 so if ith element is 6 then it should fill the 5 * 5 as 1 six times and similarly for Class2 "2" nineteen times.

EDIT: expected output for `t <- data.frame(Class1= c(6 {1st location 1,1},4,2..7{last observation}), Class2=c(19,21,23...18{last observation})`... Have put a comma just to show the separation between blocks. The thing is if we treat Class1[1] as one location it has 2 values which are 6 from class 1 and 19 from class 2. Its a satellite image pixel having two different classes for a pixel.

```
1 1 1 1 1 "1 1 1 1 2 "1 1 2 2 2 . . . . .750th 
1 2 2 2 2  2 2 2 2 2  2 2 2 2 2 . . . . .
2 2 2 2 2  2 2 2 2 2  2 2 2 2 2 . . . . . 
2 2 2 2 2  2 2 2 2 2  2 2 2 2 2 . . . . .
2 2 2 2 2  2 2 2 2 2  2 2 2 2 2 . . . . .
1 1 1 1 1
1 1 2 2 2
2 2 2 2 2
2 2 2 2 2
2 2 2 2 2
. . . . .                       1 1 1 1 1[Last block]                     
. . . . .                       1 1 2 2 2
. . . . .                       2 2 2 2 2
. . . . .                       2 2 2 2 2
. . . . .                       2 2 2 2 2
760th
```

In this fashion it would fill in 5 * 5 blocks in horizontal way, once it completes a 5* 5 block row it would then go to next 5*5 block row.

i tried but cold not get how to fill it in block wise fashion.

Comment: You can create a small dataset i.e. `t <- data.frame(Class1= c(6,4), Class2=c(19,21))` and show the expected output.  The expected output you showed is not clear with respect to how the values are filled up after first block.

Comment: I don't understand where the 0's fill in based on your comments.  You said the `3,4` blocks sit next to `1.2`.  This is what I came up with. `v1 <- c(t(t)); v2 <- rep(seq_along(v1), v1); m1 <- do.call(rbind,lapply(split(v2, as.numeric(gl(length(v2), 25, length(v2)))), matrix, 5, 5, byrow=TRUE))`

Comment: can you give us a clear example with an output as @akrun mentionned?

Comment: i just created an empty array you can say and have to fill these values in it.

Comment: Based on my example dataset `t`, I think you may need `v2 <- rep(rep(1:2, length(v1)/2), v1);do.call(rbind,lapply(split(v2, as.numeric(gl(length(v2), 25, length(v2)))), matrix, 5, 5, byrow=TRUE))` though still not clear

Comment: created the last block too....just assume you have a pixel ( a square block)with 2 values, lets say 4,6 and you have now decided to fill those values inside the square block you would then divide the square block into 10 square blocks and fill 4 in 4 blocks and rest in the leftover six blocks, like that here i have 22800 square blocks diving each square block by 5 * 5 ill get 22800 * 25 that is 570000 square blocks. now i want to fill the values as I have explained.

Comment: Updated my post with a possible solution using a small example.  Please check if that is what you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

May be

```
t1 <- data.frame(Class1=c(6,4,2, 7), Class2= c(19, 21, 23, 18))
v1 <- c(t(t1))
v2 <- rep(rep(1:2, length(v1)/2), v1)
m1 <- matrix(0,10,10)
n <- 5L
i <- (row(m1) + n-1) %/% n       
j <- (col(m1) + n-1) %/% n       
b <- i + (j - 1L) * max(i) 

indx <- as.numeric(gl(length(v2), 25, length(v2)))
lst <- split(v2, indx)
lst2 <- lapply(lst, matrix, 5, 5, byrow=TRUE)


 for(i in unique(c(b))){
    m1[b==i] <- lst2[[i]]
 }

 m1
 #     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
 #[1,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    2    2     2
 #[2,]    1    2    2    2    2    2    2    2    2     2
 #[3,]    2    2    2    2    2    2    2    2    2     2
 #[4,]    2    2    2    2    2    2    2    2    2     2
 #[5,]    2    2    2    2    2    2    2    2    2     2
 #[6,]    1    1    1    1    2    1    1    1    1     1
 #[7,]    2    2    2    2    2    1    1    2    2     2
 #[8,]    2    2    2    2    2    2    2    2    2     2
 #[9,]    2    2    2    2    2    2    2    2    2     2
 #[10,]   2    2    2    2    2    2    2    2    2     2
```

Comment: thanks but I need that 3, 4 block next to 1,2. And actually that 3,4 block should also be represented in 1,2

Comment: @RajaRaghudeepEmani  It is not clear from your example.  Please show a small example instead of the big dataset (just like I showed) and the expected result based on that.